# Issues about database queries in django

Tags: mysql, django, models

I want to get last inserted id for current user from database.I know i can get last inserted row in a table from this query     **last_inserted_id = User.objects.order_by('-id')[0]**

But if there multiple  users who are logged in to site at same time than how can I get the last inserted data for the current user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get last inserted data for the current user you should store a reference to the user in each model:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()
    inserted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)   #here
```

Then you should remember to populate this property when you create a new model.

To retrieve last inserted data for this user:

```
Album.objects.filter( inserted_by = request.user ).order_by('-id')[0]
```

Perhaps you can authomatize audits in some way. See [Full Model History snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1234/) for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand fully what you mean with *"last inserted id for current user"*. But here is an example:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)

user.save()

print user.id # prints 10 if userid is 10
```